# How to drop privileges in bash script between pipes?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, dbus, polkit

```sh
dbus-monitor --system --profile interface=org.freedesktop.login1.Session,type=signal,member={Lock,Unlock} |
  egrep --line-buffered -o 'Lock|Unlock' |
  while read SIGNAL; do
    case "${SIGNAL}" in
      Lock)
        for i in "$(systemd-path user-shared)/watchlock/lock.d/"*; do
          "${i}"
        done
        ;;
      Unlock)
        for i in "$(systemd-path user-shared)/watchlock/unlock.d/"*; do
          "${i}"
        done
        ;;
    esac
  done
```

I've made this script and I want to execute it as a regular user but `dbus-monitor` only works as root. Is there a way to execute `dbus-monitor` as root and the rest of the pipes as a regular user? Adding `sudo` before `dbus-monitor` is not an option as it is just a workaround, I could intend to execute the script as root and it would escalate privileges once again for no reason. I would also want to make use of polkit, `pkexec` for example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this:

```
cmd_a | sudo -u "${USER}" cmd_b
```

If the script is started as root, `cmd_a` will run as root and `cmd_b` will run as $USER.

Comment: > Adding `sudo` before `dbus-monitor` is not an option as it is just a workaround, I could intend to execute the script as root and it would escalate privileges once again for no reason.

Comment: Yeah, just read this. In case the script runs as root, you may do the other way around `cmd_a | sudo -u "$USER" cmd_b`

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1255613/should-i-use-sudo-in-a-script-or-sudo-an-entire-script

Comment: You are making contradicting comments here. I've first suggested that, to only run `cmd_a` as root, but you said _that's not an option_

Comment: Oh, forgot my thought. I want to escalate as less as possible, and in a way that would enable me to use polkit.

Comment: Then I suggest to use `sudo cmd_a | cmd_b` and run the main script as a normal user

Comment: Okay, you know how to persuade. Thanks.